# pivot table not grouping results as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am using sql server 2012. I have two tables, please see below

```
Table 1 (Region_Strat)

STRAT  SALES_P  COMM
EU     Bob      AC
EU     Dave     AC
NA     John     JP
GB     Mike     AC


Table 2 (Sales_Records)

SALES_P   AMT   SHOP
Bob       5     ABC
Bob       10    DEF
Bob       3     GHI
Dave      12    ABC
John      3     DEF
Mike      11    LIK
```

I have a view called vw_sales (stored as view this cannot be changed) which basically adds the STRAT column from the Region_Strat table to the Sales_Records table to give me the table below.

```
SALES_P   AMT   SHOP    STRAT
Bob       5     ABC     EU       
Bob       10    DEF     EU       
Bob       3     GHI     EU       
Dave      12    ABC     EU       
John      3     DEF     NA       
Mike      11    LIK     GB
```

This is all fine. Next I try to create piviot table (which does run but doesn't give me the result I require). My query is

```
 SELECT SHOP, [EU],[NA],[GB] 
 INTO MY_DB.dbo.TEMP
 FROM
 ( SELECT SALES.SHOP, cast(SALES.Amt as bigint) AS SumOfAmt, Region.COMM, Region.STRAT
  FROM MY_DB.dbo.vw_sales AS SALES JOIN MY_DB.dbo.Region_Strat AS Region ON
  SALES.SALES_P = Region.SALES_P
  WHERE Region.COMM in ('AC','JP') ) tbl
 pivot
 ( sum(SumOfAmt) for STRAT IN([EU],[NA],[GB])) pvt order by SHOP
```

Result I expect to see,

```
SHOP   EU    NA    GB
ABC    17    null  null     
DEF    10    3     null
GHI    3     null  null
LIK    null  null  11
```

However the result I see is shop DEF shown twice as below.

```
SHOP   EU    NA    GB
DEF    10    null  null     
DEF    null  3     null
```

How change I change my query so that DEF is shown on one row?

Comment: Is this working i don't the alias `STRAT_FUND` any where nut it is used in `where Clause` **STRAT_FUND.COMM**

Comment: apologies - a copy and paste error. It should be region, have updated in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SHOP, [EU],[NA],[GB] INTO MY_DB.dbo.TEMP
 FROM
 ( SELECT SALES.SHOP, cast(SALES.Amt as bigint) AS SumOfAmt, Region.STRAT
    FROM MY_DB.dbo.vw_sales AS SALES 
    JOIN MY_DB.dbo.Region_Strat AS Region ON SALES.SALES_P = Region.SALES_P
    WHERE Region.COMM in ('AC','JP') 
) tbl
 pivot ( sum(SumOfAmt) for STRAT IN([EU],[NA],[GB])) pvt 
 order by SHOP
```